# R - Replace list of values by another corresponding list (in data.frame or vector in R)

Tags: r

I have a `data frame` with various columns encoded as numeric (0, 0.5, 1) or binary (0, 1) information, representing various levels. Example :

```
df <- data.frame( dialogue = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0), interlocutor = c(0, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5))

#   dialogue interlocutor
# 1        1          0.0
# 2        0          1.0
# 3        1          0.5
# 4        1          0.0
# 5        0          0.5
```

The `1`/`0` options in `dialogue` mean that it IS or ISNOT a dialogue. The `0`, `0.5`, `1` in `interlocutor` correspond respectively to `System interlocutor`, `System + human interlocutor` and `Human interlocutor`.

Questions:

**1.** I understood until now that these categorical qualitative data, that I have encoded with corresponding numerical codes, should probably best be represented as `factors`. Is that right? Or is there a better way to encode this data that would allow easier processing (I'm mainly interested in descriptive statistics)?

**2.** If it is indeed the case, then how can I easily convert these numerical values to their corresponding qualitative signification?

I saw [this question-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25958089/replacing-values-in-a-column-of-a-data-frame-with-values-from-another-data-frame), so I thought about doing this:

```
# create corresponding indexes
dialogue_types <- data.frame(index = c(0, 1), value = c("No dialogue", "Dialogue")
interlocutor_types <- data.frame(
  index = c(0, 0.5, 1), 
  value = c("System interlocutor", "System + human interlocutor", "Human interlocutor")

# replace values 
dialogue_types[,2][df$dialogue]
interlocutor_types[,2][df$interlocutor]
```

Is it an adequate solution? Is there a better one? What would the optimal way of thinking this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Factors are indeed appropriate for categorical variables.

The most obvious way to create factors is the `factor` function.

```
df$dialogue_fac = factor(df$dialogue,
                     levels = c(0, 1), labels = c("No dialogue", "Dialogue"))
df$interlocutor_fac = factor(df$interlocutor,
                         levels = c(0, 0.5, 1), labels = c("System", "System + Human", "Human"))
```

Here I've added new columns so that you can easily verify that it worked, but you could just as well overwrite the old columns with the new ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I hadn't yet understood the difference between `levels` and `labels` in factors. That totally solves all my problems in a much better way that what I used to do until now!